# Searching for a file comparison program to compare folders recursively through network

Tags: data-structures, migration, compare

Yesterday we had some trouble and ended up to copy a lot of files and folders nearly manually through network from Server 1 to server 2.

Now I want to make sure that all files which exist on Server 1 are also on server 2. Server 2 can now have some additional files.

I just want a report, the program should not copy anything if not existing.

Comment: Both XCOPY and ROBOCOPY will identify such differences (copy only files that do not exist at the destination), and both have options that will display a list but not actually copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,  I found winmerge where I can use command line to compare files and use a list of arguments.

What I did is downloading winmerge installing and running the command line tool

c:\program files\WinMerge Winmergeu.exe /r /e c:data1  d:data1

A list of all Arguments which can be used is [here](http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html)

which compares recursively all data from both folders. it will display them very nicely and I could hide the files which are identical. The file which is displayed broken is the one which exist only on that folder / subfolder. Really nice tool not taking too much CPU.

I now keep it running to compare more than 1  million files....lets see how long it takes.
Of course the /r recursive will consume the most time...

[image: Winmerge Example]

Answer (score 1):

How about [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/)?

It doesn't copy anything by its own.
Maybe you need to map a local drive to the network folder not quite sure if it can handle UNC paths.